# Error installing seaborn and sklearn on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to install `seaborn` and `sklearn` on Jupyter Notebook but I always get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...` for these two libs.

These were my steps:

1. `$ conda create --name myenv`
2. `$ conda activate myenv`
3. `(myenv) $ conda install -c anaconda seaborn`
4. `(myenv) $ conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn`

When I run my python script on terminal, everything is good. No error messages. Then I start the `jupyter notebook`:

5. `(myenv) $ jupyter notebook`

And on the notebook, I only write `import seaborn as sns` and get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

The same error with `sklearn`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using the appropriate kernel (Pyrthon 2/ Python 3) where seaborn is installed?

Comment: I think so. I only have one kernel: Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you activate a Conda environment, many environmental variables are overwritten.  The `PATH` variable, however, is prepended to.  When you call `jupyter notebook`, the shell will search the `PATH`, first in your current environment, then in the base environment.

My guess is that you did not install jupyter to `my_env`, so calling `jupyter notebook` actually runs Jupyter notebook from your **base** environment.

You can test this by running:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

You can install jupyter to `my_env` via:

```
conda install -n my_env jupyter
```